# InvalidStateError when adding objects to an indexedDB object store

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I have defined IndexedDB and IDBTransaction

```
dbVersion = 1;
var db;
var dbreq;

var customerData = { ssn: "444", name: "Bill", age: 35, email: "bill@company.com"}

function create_openDB() 
{
alert('In DB function');

try {
dbreq = indexedDB.open("IndexDB", dbVersion);

dbreq.onsuccess = function (event) {
db = dbreq.result;
}

dbreq.onerror = function (event) {
console.log("indexedD Error: " + event.message);
}

dbreq.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {

var objectStore = event.target.result.createObjectStore("customers", {keyPath:"ssn"});

objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });

console.log("All object stores created");

createDatabaseObjects( event.target.result );
} 

}catch (e) {
console.log("Error: " + e.message);
}
}
```

I call this function so that indexeddb can have no issues as it works asynchronously.

```
function createDatabaseObjects( dbHandle ) {

try {

if ( dbHandle == null ) {
console.log( "Can't create database objects; the database is not open." );
} 
else 
{
console.log("in else");
```

It's working up until here. I can see this message in console. Anything further just throws an exception.

```
var transaction =  dbHandle.transaction(["customers"], "readwrite");
alert("after transaction made");


var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("customers");

var request = store.add(customerData);

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
console.log("Woot! Did it");
}
request.onerror = function(e) {
console.log("Error",e.target.error.name);
}
}
} catch (ex) { 
console.log("Message is: " +ex.message); 
}  
}
```

Comment: You make a variable called objectStore, but then use store. Could that be it?

Comment: Tried that. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you post the code in jsbin or fiddle so we can see it completely, and try running it too. Right now it is hard to tell from the code blocks above.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Here is the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98wev/6/

Comment: Your Fiddle does not work. Hitting the test button gives: Uncaught ReferenceError: create_openDB is not defined

Comment: @RaymondCamden Okay. actually, I solved the error. Many minor changes led to its working perfectly. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: A lot of times when I ask folks to simplify their issues, they end up finding it anyway. It's magic.

Comment: Hi user3603207 if you have found answer to your question please post it back here.

Comment: @RaymondCamden Haha, yes. It's kind of a placebo effect.

Comment: post the changes as answer here so that we don't have open questions, contribute back to the community!

Comment: @RaymondCamden I have aquestion though. Is there any way to perform something like a left join in indexed db?

Comment: In a traditional db, you have a table, people, with properties possibly stored in a second table, like departments, linked via a foreign key. In a system like IndexedDB, you store the *entire* object at once. Which means you don't (typically!) need to worry about joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.OIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var myIDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || { READ_WRITE: "readwrite" };
dbVersion = 1;
var db;
var dbreq;
var objectStore1;
var customerData =
{
ssn: "444", 
name: "Bill", 
email: "bill@company.com"
};

function create_openDB() 
{
    if (!window.indexedDB) 
    {
    alert("Does not support IndexedDB");
    } 
    else
    {
        alert("Supported. Go ahead");
    }
    alert('In DB function');
    try {
              dbreq = indexedDB.open("IndexDB", dbVersion);
              console.log(dbreq);
              dbreq.onsuccess = function (event) {
                  alert("Successful database creation");
             }
             dbreq.onerror = function (event) {
                 console.log("indexedD Error: " + event.message);
             }
              dbreq.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
        objectStore1 = db.createObjectStore("customers", { keyPath: "ssn" });
        console.log(objectStore1);
         objectStore1.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
         objectStore1.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });
    var dbIndex = objectStore1.index("name"); //works only if the specific index is present
                 console.log(dbIndex);

                 console.log("Object store created");

                 createDatabaseObjects(db);
                } 
        }catch (e) {
             console.log("Error: " + e.message);
         }
 }


function createDatabaseObjects(dbHandle) {
 try 
 {
 if ( dbHandle == null ) {
    console.log( "Can't create database objects; the database is not open." );
   } 
   else 
   {
  console.log("in else");
  objectStore1.transaction.oncomplete = function(e)
  {
         var trans = dbHandle.transaction(["customers"], "readwrite");
        console.log("after transaction");

        var customers1 = trans.objectStore("customers");
         var request = customers1.put(customerData);

        request.onsuccess = function(e) {
         dbHandle.objectStoreId = request.result;
         console.log(request.result);
         console.log("Woot! Did it");
        }
        request.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("Error",e.target.error.name);
        }

    }
}

 } catch (ex) { 
    console.log("Message is: " +ex.message); 
}  
}
```